# awk keep only the first and last value on comma-seaparated field

Tags: awk

Hi' I am trying to keep only first and last value of comma-separated field on my data. Following is how my input data would look like

```
a    1   y    1,2,4,3,6,2,1
b    2   y    3,56,3,2,1
c    3   n    4,3,2,1,4
```

I just want to keep first and last value on the 4th coulmn of my data so that my data would look like this:

```
a    1    y    1,1
b    2    y    3,1
c    3    n    4,4
```

Can you anyone help me how to do this? Thank you

Comment: You have asked a few questions that are very minor variations on each other. What have you learned given all the answers you've received?

Comment: I would say not much. Next time post what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$NF}' input.txt
```

---

- `-F,` input field separator
- `-vOFS=,` output field separator
- `$1` the 1st field
- `$NF` the last field

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F, '{ printf "%s,%s\n", $1, $NF}'` should do the job!

Comment: in fact, I tested printf but got a strange behaviour, but this was my term's fault. Edited ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk command:

```
awk '{size = split($4,numbers,",")}   {print $1" "$2" "$3" "numbers[1]","numbers[size]}'
```

This splits the fourth field into an array, saves the size as `size`, prints the first 3 fields, then the first and last elements of the `numbers` array.

Answer (score 1):

If your other fields can contain commas:

```
$ awk '{sub(/,.*,/,",",$NF)}1' file
a 1 y 1,1
b 2 y 3,1
c 3 n 4,4
```

If not:

```
$ awk '{sub(/,.*,/,",")}1' file
a    1   y    1,1
b    2   y    3,1
c    3   n    4,4
```